# vertex AI batch prediction problem, got error for jsonl file

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

i just trained a video classification model on vertex AI. When i do batch prediction, i got the following error from vertex AI:

BatchPrediction could not start because no valid instances were found in the input file.
Error: On line 1 of gs://cloud-ai-platform-b65d18b2-d59a-4c4b-884b-d1e9bbbcb8a0/output.jsonl: The line cannot be parsed.

The following is the content of my output.jsonl file.

{"videoGcsUri":"gs://cloud-ai-platform-b65d18b2-d59a-4c4b-884b-d1e9bbbcb8a0/1.avi","timeSegmentAnnotations":[{"displayName":"align","startTime":"0.0s","endTime":"1.0s"}],"dataItemResourceLabels":{"aiplatform.googleapis.com/ml_use":"test"}}

I am a bit confused which part in my output.jsonl causes this error, as the message from vertex AI is not that helpful. Thank you in advance.:)